# How strict is FlixBus about its "No electric or folding bikes" policy?

Tags: europe, buses, bicycles, flixbus

I've been thinking of buying a bike here, but since I take frequent trips on FlixBus for short vacations I went to review their [policy on bikes](https://www.flixbus.com/service/bike-travel). Unfortunately they for some reason forbid electric and folding bikes, even if you book a bike carrier. What is the reason for this policy? How strict are they about this - does anyone have experience? What if I got a bike with a removable battery and removed it and packed it separately in my luggage, would it be better then?

Comment: I'm not surprised they don't allow e-bikes.  Most e-bikes are expensive, heavy, and bulky.  I _am_ surprised they don't allow folding bikes, if they allow bicycles at all.  Maybe folding bikes are more prone to get damaged in transit?

Comment: The website you linked says folding and e-bikes can't be transported **on the bike carrier**. The bike rack is desgined specifically for unfolded bicycles, so there may be no way to properly secure a folding bicycle. If you pack the folding bike in case of appropriate size, to be stowed along with other cases, they may not know or care.

Comment: An e-bike may also exceed the weight limit of the carrier or prevent multiple bikes from being loaded safely.

Comment: If it was about folded size or the weight of bikes, then I suspect they would just write down those limitations: Weight limit X kg, all folding bikes must be transported unfolded firmly

Comment: Most folding bicycles have a different structure and do not fit well, or at all, on most bike carriers. I bet that if you show up with a 'non folding' bike in the same layout at folders it will also not be accepted. (Nor would my recumbent bikes, I guess.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website seems pretty clear to me. You have two options:

1. Bike Carrier:
   This option is only available for regular non-foldable bicycles.
2. Baggage Compartment:
   This option is available for regular and foldable bicycles. But you need a bicycle bag, and you might have to partially disassemble your regular bike to fit the size requirements.

Electric bikes, tandems, and tricycles are simply not allowed. If, as I suspect, they are worried about your e-battery bursting into flames, they won't let you take the battery as carry-on luggage either.

Comment: IMO this doesn't really answer the question of how it works in practice. It might be that bus drivers don't really care and would let you bring any bike on board.

Comment: @JonathanReez: FlixBus Europe operates routes all the way from Bucharest to London. I don't think the flexibility of their drivers is something that can be answered in general terms.

Comment: E-bikes can be transported as special baggage (subject to availability).

Comment: @zhantongz: [the website](https://global.flixbus.com/service/bike-travel) has a paragraph titled "Bike Transportation in the Baggage Compartment". The last item in that paragraph is "No e-bikes, tandems or tricycles".

Comment: @JonathanReez But it's the safe answer.  Would you want to show up for a trip with your e-bike and only then discover that you can't take it along because that particular driver isn't as flexible as others?